# How to dispatch an action after catchError in an rxjs epic

Tags: error-handling, rxjs, action

I am using rxjs and I would like to fire an error handling epic, if an error is caught in my code.

```
export const exampleLogin = (action$: AnyAction, state$: any) => action$.pipe(
ofType(appActions.APP_START),
withLatestFrom(state$),
concatMap(() => from(getUser())),
pipe(
    map(loginActions.loginSuccess),
    tap(() => console.log('Silent login success'))
),
catchError((err: any) => {
    console.log(err);
    loginActions.errorHandler();
    return empty();
}
));
```

The console.log part of the code executes, but my errorHandler function doesn't. If I add the errorHandler to the first pipe, it runs. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: you should show the code for errorHandler

Comment: Well, it's not being called at all.

Comment: To have a complete understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I think you use the inner `pipe` in a wrong way. You could do something like:

```
concatMap(() => from(getUser()).pipe(
    map(loginActions.loginSuccess),
    tap(() => console.log('Silent login success'))
)),
catchError((err: any) => {
    console.log(err);
    loginActions.errorHandler();
    return empty();
})
```